# List of campsites on Sardinia

Tags: camping, campers, sardinia

I'm looking for campsites on Sardinia. We travelling without car, just backpacking.
Priorities are: nature (we usually go to the mountains), not that many people, cheap.

Is there some guide with list of campsites on Sardinia?

Comment: When you write 'camp' I assume you mean campsite where more people can stay as individuals. The usual (for me at least) meaning for the word 'camp' is a site where a group of (often young) people stay together for a week or a few weeks.